# WSO2 api manager - refresh token request format

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

After retrieving an access token from an WSO2 api manager, what request needs to be made using the refresh token to obtain a new access token?

Is this documented anywhere? I have had a hunt around but have had no luck.

Thanks

Comment: I want to refresh token from my C#.net application. Can someone please provide me the exact configuration parameters to configure in my code. I am not sure how to configure this curl url in my C#.NET code.

Answer (score 1):

Sample curl request format can be listed as follow.

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=<refreshtoken>&scope=PRODUCTION" -H "Authorization: Basic <Base64 encoded consumer secret and key seperated by semicolan>, Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:8243/token
```

More info can found under **Renewing access tokens** section in documentation.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Token+API

Answer (score 1):

Sample curl request should be as below

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=refreshtoken>&scope=PRODUCTION" -H "Authorization: Basic "<Base64 encoded consumer secret and key seperated by semicolan>" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:8243/token
```